# libbpf failed to open system Kconfig when using 'bpftool struct_ops' command

Tags: ebpf, bpf, libbpf

I am trying to use the [bpf_cubic](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/progs/bpf_cubic.c) example in the linux kernel as a sample to load onto kernel using `bpftool struct_ops` command. The code is compiled successfully, but when I run `bpftool struct_ops register bpf_cubic.o`, it results in the following error:

```
libbpf: failed to open system Kconfig
libbpf: failed to load object 'bpf_cubic.o'
```

Any ideas on what the issue might be?

- Edit:

Following is the output of `strace -f -ebpf bpftool struct_ops register bpf_cubic.o`:

```
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x7ffd21f7caf0, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0, fd_array=NULL}, 144) = 3
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x7ffd21f7c8e0, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0}, 116) = 3
bpf(BPF_PROG_LOAD, {prog_type=BPF_PROG_TYPE_SOCKET_FILTER, insn_cnt=2, insns=0x7ffd21f7caf0, license="GPL", log_level=0, log_size=0, log_buf=NULL, kern_version=KERNEL_VERSION(0, 0, 0), prog_flags=0, prog_name="", prog_ifindex=0, expected_attach_type=BPF_CGROUP_INET_INGRESS, prog_btf_fd=0, func_info_rec_size=0, func_info=NULL, func_info_cnt=0, line_info_rec_size=0, line_info=NULL, line_info_cnt=0, attach_btf_id=0, attach_prog_fd=0, fd_array=NULL}, 128) = 3
libbpf: failed to open system Kconfig
libbpf: failed to load object 'bpf_cubic.o'
+++ exited with 255 +++
```

Output of `uname -r`:

```
6.1.45-8-esx
```

Output of `ls -l /boot/config*`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 125476 Sep 20 07:09 /boot/config-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx
```

However, I should point out that after I used menuconfig to enable BTF support and other related feature to work with bpftool, I changed the image used by grub located at `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` to point to the vmlinuz file created after compiling the new kernel. What I want to say is that the config file shown in the output of `ls -l /boot/config*` is the old config file which does not have the mentioned features enabled.

Below is the output of ls `/boot/`:

```
config-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx      linux-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx.cfg   System.old
efi                          photon.cfg                   vmlinuz
grub                         systemd.cfg                  vmlinuz-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx
grub2                        System.map                   vmlinuz.old
initrd.img-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx  System.map-6.1.45-8.ph5-esx
```

Comment: The first is actually a warning and likely a red herring. The second is more likely the real failure. On what kernel version are you trying this? Could you share the output of `strace -f -ebpf bpftool struct_ops register bpf_cubic.o`?

Comment: I am using Photon OS 5 optimized for esx based on kernel version 6.1.45. 
I also added the output of the requested command as an edit to the question.

Comment: I was a bit too quick to dismiss the first warning. Considering the OS and reading the bpftool source code, it looks like that's the issue. Could you add to the question the outputs of `uname -r` and `ls -l /boot/config*`? I wonder if WMware might have changed the name of that kernel config file slightly.

Comment: I provided the information you asked. I believe it might be something wrong with the change I made to the /boot section. I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The config file for the running kernel should be in `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` for bpftool to succeed.

---

**Explanations**

To load this specific BPF program, bpftool needs access to the kernel config file. That's because [the BPF program refers to one kernel config](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.5/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/progs/bpf_cubic.c#L109).

The libbpf library (used by bpftool to load BPF programs) [expects the kernel configuration](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v6.5/tools/lib/bpf/libbpf.c#L1971) to be in either `/boot/config-$(uname -r)` or `/proc/config.gz`.

An easy way to fix it would be to copy the config file for the running kernel to `/boot/config-$(uname -r)`. Another solution would be to edit `bpf_cubic.c` to hardcode the value of `CONFIG_HZ`.